# Prettier removes 2 empty lines

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, newline, prettier

I'm using Visual Studio Code and the prettier plugin. I also have created my own prettier config file:

.prettierrc.json:

```
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "useTabs": true,
  "tabWidth": 4
}
```

and this code gets reformatted by prettier and the 2 empty lines are completely removed (it's a TypeScript file):
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
    selector: 'warning-alert',
    templateUrl: './warningAlert.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./warningAlert.component.css'],
})


export class WarningAlert {}
```

becomes:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'warning-alert',
    templateUrl: './warningAlert.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./warningAlert.component.css'],
})
export class WarningAlert {}
```

As far as I read it should remove multiple empty lines to 1 empty lines, but not completely remove every empty line?
Neither I can't find an option in the Visual Studio Code Settings for prettier nor for the native prettier.

Answer (score 0):

defaultExpression: ^\n

issueExpression: ^\s*\n

By default, prettier is set to remove empty lines by find & replace using defaultExpression. The problem stated here is regarding prettier using find & replace using issueExpression.

In VS Code, you can go to settings.json file and put these lines stated below:

```
"[typescript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false,
    "editor.suggest.insertMode": "replace",
    "editor.semanticHighlighting.enabled": true
  },
```

Here, instead of [typescript], you need to replace it with the language you're working on like `[javascript] or [react]`.
The solution here is,

`"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",`

will use the correct version of prettier, and on saving your file it will use the expected defaultExpression to find & replace the empty lines.

Thus, you will still get to see 1 empty line.